# adding input field dynamically causes problems

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm working on a html page and I have a problem when adding a new input field to the form. The problem is that, the content of the other input fields is resetted when the new field is added.

The code for adding a new input text is the following:

```
var TSLOT = 
[   "<div id=\"TSLOT_n_\">",
    "From: <input type=\"text\" id=\"from_n_\" autocomplete=\"off\">",
    "By letter: <input type=\"text\" id=\"letter_n_\" autocomplete=\"off\">",
    "To: <input type=\"text\" id=\"to0-_n_\" autocomplete=\"off\">",
    "<input type=\"text\" id=\"to1-_n_\" autocomplete=\"off\">",
    "<BR></div>" ].join("");

function addSlotTransition() { 
document.getElementById( "Delta" ).innerHTML += TSLOT.replace( /_n_/g, Delta_size++ ); }
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are the other input fields also in `document.getElementById("Delta")`? If so, this would explain the problem: you're replacing all the input fields so their content is reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `.innerHTML`, it creates a new DOM tree from the parsed *innerHTML* and rewrites it, so everything not present in the HTML is lost. Use a real append:

```
 document.getElementById( "Delta" ).insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', TSLOT.replace( /_n_/g, Delta_size++ ) );
```

#### JS Fiddle Demo

Comment: Now I understand the issue. Ooooh yeah now it works!!